# copy selected data from source sheet to new sheet

Tags: excel

I have this sheet B2B where there are some unwanted rows I want to remove. The B2B sheet should not be edited. I need to create, Move and make a copy of B2B sheet and rename the copy sheet to 2B, then I want to delete all the rows if those rows fulfill 3 conditions.

1. In B2B sheet if the column H contains Yes or Y shift both.
2. In B2B sheet if the Invoice value and Taxable value in one row are the same. Columns F and J.
3. In B2B sheet if columns J K and L value is 0

I have included in the data all the 3 kinds of rows as per each condition which are not to be shown in 2B sheet I have also colored the cells to yellow for your reference.
[8. Delete unwanted rows and create B2B Edited](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ss4_v_rsQJ2hceNgUC2rfHXW0aMepSTe/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100073130462255190627&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: I do not know how to attach my file. Can someone please suggest how to ??

Comment: You can't attach files here. You can link to other websites though users may be reluctant to download those so post a screenshot or two and any code you've tried.

Comment: I hope I have done that right.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is likely to be closed if it amounts to nothing more than a list of requests - this site is for helping people with code so you must show what you have tried.

Comment: Sorry. I have been doing this manually. As there are more than a 1000 rows to check I thought a code will do it faster. Since I have no idea how to write a code I was expecting someone would be able to help me with a code.

Comment: I checked many videos online how to do the above. But writing the criteria I have no idea at all.

Comment: Miraculously, your question is not closed. To answer, I need a few clarifications. What does `shift both` mean? If `F=J` and `J:L=0` then the whole thing will only be true if also `F=0` and you might as well scratch your 2nd condition and use `F,JKL=0` in the 3rd. Maybe you switched a column or two. Please clarify. It would help if you upload your file once more since the current link is dead.

Comment: The issue was resolved long back. Thanks for trying to help.